# How to write a function that replaces first character of each input string by a given custom character?

Tags: haskell

For instance, if we want to replace each character with a letter 'B'

EXAMPLE:

```
replace["Fiba","Voba","Lidi"] = ["Biba","Boba","Bidi"]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You generally get the best answers by avoiding open-ended questions and instead showing an attempt you have made (even if it doesn't work yet), which the other people can then use as a base to guide you to a better solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to start by constructing the function that will do this on a single string, which is to say, the function that maps "Fiba" to "Biba." That should look something like this:

```
replace1 :: String -> String
replace1 (_:xs) = 'B' : xs
```

This makes use of a pattern match over the constructor `(:)`, which means that `_` is the first character of the string and `xs` is the rest. (`_` is a special name that can be assigned multiple values, but not used. It's mainly used for throwing values away that you don't need, like the first character of the original string in this example.) Then you can define your `replace` function as

```
replace :: [String] -> [String]
replace = map replace1
```

EDIT: The provided example code should now work.

Comment: Well, that's what I get for trying to write Haskell without a compiler at hand.